# Parse json from bandsintown API

Tags: json, api, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have trouble to parse and show events from Bands in Town´s API in my appcelerator mobile app. (iOS)
This is my bands event that i want to show in a table.
http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/Lucy%20Seven/events.json?api_version=2.0&app_id=LucySeven
And this is the code that i have for showing it

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

win.hideNavBar();

Ti.UI.backgroundColor = '#050505';

var url = "http://api.bandsintown.com/artists/Lucy%20Seven/events.json?      api_version=2.0&app_id=LucySeven"

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({

        backgroundColor: '#050505',
        separatorColor:'#110000',
    });
var tableData = [];
var json, artists, name, picture, title, description;

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
onload: function() {
// Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
for (i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
    data = json.data[i];
    row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height:'100dp',
        backgroundColor: '#050505',
        separatorColor:'#110000',
    });
  var  name = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: title,
        font:{
            fontSize:'17dp',
        fontWeight:'bold'
    },
    height:'auto',
    left:'90dp',
    top:'20dp',
    color:'#eee',
    touchEnabled:true
    });
    row.add(name);


        var  start = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:   description,
        font:{
            fontSize:'12dp'
        },
    height:'auto',
    left:'90dp',
    bottom:'20dp',
    color:'#eee',
    touchEnabled:true
    });
    row.add(start);


  // Avatar
            var img = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image   : thumb_url ,
                width   : 70,
                height  : 70,
                top     : 5,
                bottom  : 5,
                borderRadius: 5,
                borderColor: '#eee',
                left    : 5
            });
            row.add(img);


    tableData.push(row);
    }

table.setData(tableData);
},
onerror: function(e) {
Ti.API.debug("STATUS: " + this.status);
Ti.API.debug("TEXT:   " + this.responseText);
Ti.API.debug("ERROR:  " + e.error);
alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Try again.');
},
timeout:5000
});

xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```

There is a API responses for json here:
http://www.bandsintown.com/api/responses#events-json
I really cant see what is wrong... Maybe im to blind to see what i have missed?
I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction on this.
i have tried with: data.title data.artists.title title artists.titel and so on but nothing have shown up in my tableview.....
Thanx
//R

Comment: What's it doing or not doing that's wrong? Are you getting an error? What's the exact text and line of the error message?

Comment: No error or something like that.  I just cant get anything to show.  It wont show anything in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the value of `this.responseText` and what's the value of `json` after `JSON.parse`? In the JSON response I don't see a `data` property so I'm not sure what `json.data` is supposed to be. Also in `Ti.UI.createLabel` you give `test: title` but `title` is never given a value.

I suspect what you really want in your `for` loop is this:

```
json = JSON.parse( this.responseText ); // `json` will be an array of objects

for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  data = json[ i ];
  // ...

  var name = Ti.UI.createLabel( {
    text: data.title,
    // ...
  } );
}
```

The key to debugging this is the same as debugging many things—find out what data you have at each step (I've never used Titanium but it must have something like `console.log` at the very least) and figure out how it differs from what you expect.

Comment: Yepp! That did the trick! i Can get the ID and description to show now! :) I still cant get the name or picture but maybe it just takes some time fooling around and i will get it.  Thanx man! It is´nt easy to be a low budget band and do everything without a budget.  Cheers!

Comment: The artists' names and pictures should be `json[i].artists[j].name` (where `j` is `0` for the first, `1` for the next, etc.) and `.image_url` respectively. Good luck!